# mongoDB slow full-text search & db crash

Tags: php, mongodb

I created a text index like this:

```
{
    "brand" : 1,
    "color" : 1,
    "han" : 1,
    "name" : 1,
    "price" : 1
}
```

And I try to search for a keyword with this php code:

```
// select a database
$db = $m->computerdb;

// select a collection 
$collection = $db->products;

$result = $collection->find(array('$text' => array('$search' => 'Asus')), array('pictures' => 0))->limit(1);

// iterate through the results
foreach ($result as $document) {
    echo $document["name"] . "\n";
}
```

getting the one result takes more than one minute. Sometimes the database crashes in different ways, by doing exactly the same query:

```
2016-09-25T15:16:15.008-0400 F -        [conn7] out of memory.
```

or

```
2016-09-25T15:26:26.404-0400 E STORAGE  [conn3] WiredTiger (12) [1474831586:358439][1069:0x7f7395f5c700], file:collection-2-161678893487581897.wt, WT_CURSOR.search: memory allocation of 7098127 bytes failed: Cannot allocate memory
2016-09-25T15:26:26.540-0400 I -        [conn3] Invariant failure: seekRet resulted in status UnknownError: 12: Cannot allocate memory at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_record_store.cpp 527
```

I tried to increase the RAM from 4GB to 16GB and rewrote the text index but still the same problem. What am I doing wrong? The database counts 8325 documents and is about 7GB.

Comment: Did you got the solution. kindly post..I encountered same issue

Comment: sorry can't remember, if you find a solution maybe post it here. :)